# Is there a code analysis tool that can reduce my conditional branching?

Tags: software-development, c, programming, code-analysis

I want to reduce the deep nested branching of this C code and I wonder if there is an analysis tool that can make a truth table for the conditions or if I must analyze it manually? I'd like to make the code more readable and less branching. My IDE CLion from JetBrains doesn't say anything about how to perform such a refactoring. Can it be automated? I didn't try use Lint but I could try it.

```
if (ptr + j) {
    if (*(ptr + j)[0] == '{') {
        keep = true;
    }
    if (testFn(*(ptr + j))) { /* test for last char */
        string[i][j - p] = concat(*pString1, *(ptr + j));
        keep = false;
        free(*pString1);
        goto mylabel;
    }
    if (keep) {
        *pString1 = concat(*pString1, *(ptr + j));
        *pString1 = concat(*pString1, " ");
        p++;
    } else {
        b1 = false;
        int q = j;
        for (e = 0; *(ptr + q + e); e++) { /* step through the string */
            b1 = true;
            if (*(ptr + e + q)) {
                *pString = concat(*pString, *(ptr + e + q));
                *pString = concat(*pString, " ");
            }
            j = e;
        }
        if (makeArgs(*pString, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, i, h)) {
            write_command(&w, argv, string[w]);
            w++;

        } else {
            if (!b1) { /* no args (?) */
                for (int r = 0; argv[r] != NULL; r++) {
                    string[i][r] = argv[r]; /* is this necessary? */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been able to reduce the conditional branching manually, but I havn't done a truth table. I think the code analyses should say which branches are identical and when with a truth table.

The complete function looks like this today:

```
static int runCmd(const char *cmd) {
    const char *cp;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    struct command structcommand[15];
    char **argv = 0;
    int argc = 1;
    bool pipe = false;
    char *string[z][z];
    char *pString3[40];
    char *pString2[40];
    int n = 0;
    char **ptr1;
    char string1[z];
    bool keep = false;
    char *pString1[z];
    char *pString[z];
    *pString1 = "\0";
    *pString = "\0";
    char *temp = {'\0'};
    int w = 0;
    bool quote = false;
    int rrs[256];
    int j = 0;
    int i;
    int p = 0;
    char **ptr;
    int count = 0;
    char *cmdtmp;
    bool b1 = false;
    int y = 0;
    i = 0;
    int h = 0;
    char *str;
    char *freeme[75][75];
    char **dealloc[75];
    char **dealloca[75][75];
    int acount[128];
    nullterminate(string);
    int rr = 0;
    for (z = 0; z < 128; z++) {
        acount[z] = -1;

    }
    for (int f = 0; f < 75; f++) {
        dealloc[f] = NULL;
        for (z = 0; z < 75; z++) {
            freeme[f][z] = NULL;
        }
    }
    if (cmd) {
        for (cp = cmd; *cp; cp++) {
            if ((*cp >= 'a') && (*cp <= 'z')) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((*cp >= 'A') && (*cp <= 'Z')) {
                continue;
            }
            if (isDecimal(*cp)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (isBlank(*cp)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((*cp == '.') || (*cp == '/') || (*cp == '-') ||
                (*cp == '+') || (*cp == '=') || (*cp == '_') ||
                (*cp == ':') || (*cp == ',') || (*cp == '\'') ||
                (*cp == '"')) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        cmdtmp = strdup(cmd);
        ptr1 = str_split(pString3, cmdtmp, '|');
        if (strstr(cmd, "|") == NULL) {         /* not a pipeline */
            makeArgs(cmd, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, 0, 0);
            write_argument(&argc, structcommand, argv, string[0]);
            n++;
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; *(ptr1 + i); i++) { /* loop for each pipeline*/
                n++;
                /* save number of pipelines */
                dealloc[n] = NULL;
                int e = 0; /* a counter */
                *pString = "\0"; /* should malloc and free this? */
                strcpy(string1, *(ptr1 + i));
                if ((string1[0] != '\0') &&
                    !isspace(string1[0])) { /* this is neither the end nor a new argument */ /* BSD bug? check*/

                    ptr = str_split(pString2, *(&string1), ' '); /* split the string at the arguments */
                    dealloc[rr] = ptr;
                    rr++;
                    h = 0;
                    for (j = 0; *(ptr + j); j++) { /* step through the arguments */
                        dealloca[n][n - 1] = NULL;
                        /* the pipeline is in cmdtmp and the argument/program is in ptr[i] */
                        if (ptr + j && !quote && strstr(*(ptr + j), "'")) { /* is quote? */
                            quote = true;
                            strcpy(temp, *(ptr + j)); /* point where quoted piipelines crash */
                            if (y < 1) {
                                y++;
                            }
                        }
                        while (quote) {
                            if (*(ptr + j) && strstr(*(ptr + j), "'")) { /* end of quote */
                                quote = false;
                                if (y < 1) {
                                    string[i][j] = strcpy(temp, *(ptr + j));
                                }
                                y = 0;
                            }
                            else if (*(ptr + j)) { /* read until end of quote */
                                string[i][j] = temp;
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                quote = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (ptr + j) { ;
                            if (*(ptr + j)[0] == '{') {
                                keep = true;
                            }
                            if (testFn(*(ptr + j))) { /* test for last char */
                                string[i][j - p] = concat(*pString1, *(ptr + j));
                                keep = false;
                                free(*pString1);
                                continue;//goto mylabel;
                            }
                            if (keep) {
                                str = concat(*pString1, *(ptr + j));
                                *pString1 = concat(str, " ");
                                free(str);
                                p++;
                            } else {
                                b1 = false;
                                int q = j;
                                freeme[i][0] = *pString;
                                for (e = 0; *(ptr + q + e); e++) { /* step through the string */
                                    b1 = true;
                                    if (*(ptr + e + q)) {
                                        str = concat(*pString, *(ptr + e + q));

                                        *pString = concat(str, " "); /* how to free() ? */
                                        free(str);
                                        freeme[i][e] = *pString;



                                    }
                                    j = e; /* adjust the counter */
                                }


                                if (makeArgs(freeme[i][e - 1], &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, i, h)) {
                                    write_command(&w, argv, string[w]);
                                    w++;
                                    for (int qwe = 0; qwe < argc; qwe++) {

                                        dealloca[n - 1][qwe] = &argv[qwe];
                                    }
                                    acount[n - 1] = argc;

                                } else {
                                    if (!b1) { /* no args (?) */
                                        for (int r = 0; argv[r] != NULL; r++) {
                                            string[i][r] = argv[r]; /* is this necessary? */
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    bool boo = false;
                    dump_argv((const char *) "d", argc, argv, boo);
                }



            }


        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            structcommand[i].argv = string[i];
            for (j = 0; string[i][j] != NULL; j++) {
                if (string[i] != NULL) {


                }
            }



        }
        free(cmdtmp);
        if (ptr1) {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; *(ptr1 + i); i++) {

                free(*(ptr1 + i));
            }
            printf("\n");
            free(ptr1);
        }

        fflush(NULL);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork failed");
            return -1;
        }
        /* If we are the child process, then go execute the string.*/
        if (pid == 0) {
            /* spawn(cmd);*/
            fork_pipes(n, structcommand);
        }
        /*
         * We are the parent process.
         * Wait for the child to complete.
         */
        status = 0;
        while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));
        if (pid < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                    (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));

            return -1;
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        for (j = 0; string[i][j] != NULL; j++) {
            if (string[i] != NULL) {

                if (string[i][j])
                    free(string[i][j]);

            }
        }

    }

    int z;
    for (int f = 0; f < n; f++) {
        if (f > 0) {

        }
        for (z = 0; freeme[f][z]; z++) {

            free(freeme[f][z]);
        }

    }

    size_t idx;
    for (int f = 0; n > 1 && f < n; f++) {

        for (idx = 0; *(dealloc[f] + idx) != NULL; idx++) {
            free(*(dealloc[f] + idx));
        }
        free(dealloc[f]);

    }

    return WEXITSTATUS(status);


}
```

The code is scanning and parsing another program, that's why it is so much string manipulation, saving and looking ahead at characters and pointers.

Comment: If your code still uses `goto` - so avoiding the use of keep then you have not done well.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I should be able to rewrite the `goto` but I actually like it because it is so rare. We can do it with 'break`, `continue` that I also like better than variables. In fact, if you program in assembly you do `goto` often.

Comment: Yes it is essential in assembler but considered **very** bad practice is C due to the issues with a) maintenance issues & b) stack corruption because it is too easy to `goto` somewhere outside of the function or procedure - not return. That is why it is rare!

Comment: [My project](https://github.com/montao/openshell) is approx. 2000 lines of code and I used `goto` only once because I was lazy. I promise I will change it to a `break` or a `continue` but I don't like `boolean` ...

Comment: Your code appears to inspect an uninitialized value of keep, if your first two (nested) conditionals both evaluate to false.   That's either a bug or you didn't show us all relevant code.

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes, it looks that way but it is initialized. I'm mostly concerned about correctness, readability and maintainability so I use the tool Valgrind to work out all my bugs and memory leaks. Even if the program runs "perfectly" it can have memory leaks that don't show until an analysis discovers the bugs.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "truth table"? Do you want to know what the full condition is under which every block of code executes? (e.g., for the then part of "if (keep)", the full condition would be "*(ptr + j)[0] == '{' && !testFn(*(ptr + j)):?  You should update your question to make what you want for this explicit.

Comment: This code is very strange.  I assume "ptr" is declared as "char *".    How can "ptr+j" ever be zero?  Can you explain what "*(ptr+j)[0]" does? Does it actually compile?

Comment: @IraBaxter Usually this is done with an "abstract syntax tree" with a recursive descent parser algorithm but I have done it with loops and a matrix that represents a program where the first row is the first pipe and the first column of the first row is the first argument of the first pipe. `*(ptr + j)[0] ` is actually very concrete the current character of what is being scanned, `ptr` is the beginning of the pipe and j is the offset. 0 means first character of the argument. Specification [here](pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html).

Comment: OK, so "ptr" is declared "**char".  How can "ptr+j" ever be zero? You didn't answer the question about what you explicitly want for "truth tables".   (Are all those array sizes really hardwired?  This isn't preprocessed code; it still contains comments).   (Yes, I know about recursive descent parsers, but I usually don't implement them like this: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769)

Comment: I might be able to do it with recursion (which is used to call `fork` and `exec` , but loops are faster and easier for my to code than recursion. I think the idea is good to make a truth table for the conditions to see if something is always or never true because I am not experienced at this detailed level of C pointer so far, but I'm working on it. You can find the entire repository [here](https://github.com/montao/openshell) for this thing which is my own shell similar to `sash` or `dash` . It's interesting that Valgrind can find so much about the RAM, I wrote a test that uses Valgrind.

Comment: Not an automated tool, but a standard way to write goto-free programs without using extra variables: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36661381/120163

Comment: Analysis cannot modify your code. Analysis is a read-only operation. Maybe get familiar with some concepts first, e.g. https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/brownfield Write unit tests, measure the code coverage or better branch coverage. Then look for an IDE which has refactoring methods like "Extract method" and "Invert if statement", something like Jetbrains Resharper but for C. It does identify logical errors like "This if condition is always true".

Comment: Rewrite this with classes (c++) and polymorphism and avoid branching.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519515/how-can-polymorphism-replace-an-if-else-statement-inside-of-a-loop

Comment: Also check this out : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/47789/how-would-you-refactor-nested-if-statements and this : http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/refactoring-deeply-nested-code/231500074?pgno=1

Comment: You might consider simply reorganizing the code to make it readable. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/37079307/120163

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes. My IDE tells me when a condition is "always true" and then I could remove it. Today I'm learning how to make a grammar but I'm stuck on how to  implement rules. I try this with the lemon parser for a `while` keyword `expr(A)::= WHILE LPAR expr(B) RPAR expr(C). {printf("test"); }` but the test string doesn't print. My code got messy and I'm trying to make a grammar instead.

Comment: You really, really don't want to build your own C parser.  First, its a lot harder than it looks, because C is a lot messier than you think it is, the compilers disagree on what is legal, and you have to get the preprocessor right.  If you manage to do all of that, you next problem is that a parser is just not good enough to do much with.  See my essay on http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks Ira! I bookmarked the links. But I must learn how to write grammar. I'm learning the lemon parser and can almost do the `while` keyword based on the simple calculator. Now they say on code review today that my code shows "a lot" of improvement: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128149/running-shell-commands-in-a-pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve had some success using a tool called [CppCheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) via a Jenkins CI system.  I don’t specifically track conditional branches, but, the amount of [checks](https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/wiki/ListOfChecks/) this tool provides is worth the look. In particular, check the `Condition` part which lists various checks for conditions that are always true/false (including value tracking, duplicate conditions, interval logic), but other categories also list some possibly useful checks like:

- “pointer addition in condition“
- “identical code in both branches of if/else or ternary operator.”
- other types of suspicious or redundant conditions (for STL, strings, logic/numeric operations, ...)

And, it’s available as a [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8143) for your IDE.

Comment: *“identical code in both branches of if/else or ternary operator.”*  Wow.  That's the most interesting example of what CppCheck can do?  I've been coding for 45 years and I've never encountered this.